# Map-Function for User-defined Generic Lists

Tags: sml, ml

I'm trying to define a new polymorphic type `generic_list` with two value constructors: `List` and `Seq`, and add the function `map_function (proc, items)` that maps `proc` over all items.

Here is what I have so far:

```
datatype 'a seq = Nil | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a seq);
datatype 'a generic_list = List of 'a list | Seq of 'a seq;
```

How can I build the `map_function`
when I have the following requirements:

- Signature: `generic_map (proc, items)`
- Purpose: Same as `map` defined in class, but items can be either a regular list or a lazy list.
- Type: `fn: ('a -> 'b) * 'a generic_list -> 'b generic_list`
- Examples:

  ```
  generic_map (fn x => x + 10, List [1, 2, 3]);
  val it = List [12,13,14]: int generic_list

  generic_map (fn x => x + 10, Seq (Cons (1, fn () => Cons(2, fn () => Cons (3, fn () => Nil)))));
  val it = Seq (Cons (11, fn)): int generic_list
  ```

Comment: I think in your first example, the result should be `List [11, 12, 13]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing by *`map` defined in class* you mean the `map` function for lists from the [Standard ML Basis Library](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html)? Anyway, you have a data type with two constructors, one for `List`s and one for `Seq`s, thus at the top-level, your function should just distinguish those two cases, i.e.,

```
fun generic_map (f, List xs) = List (...) (*map f over xs*)
  | generic_map (f, Seq s)   = Seq (...) (*map f over s*)
```

For the first case you get what you need almost for free by using `List.map`. The only remaining thing is to define a map-function for lazy lists. Its shape will be something like:

```
fun map_seq (f, Nil) = ... (*map f over the empty sequence*)
  | map_seq (f, Cons (x, s)) = ... (*map f over x and the remaining sequence s*)
```

**Remark:** Since it is part of your specification, you might not be allowed to change it -- and maybe it is more a matter of taste -- but I find your type for lazy lists a bit odd, because the tail of a lazy list, in your case, does not have the same type as a lazy list (i.e., the head of a list is not accessed lazily). In similar situations I would rather use

```
datatype 'a cell = Nil | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a cell);
type 'a seq = (unit -> 'a cell);
```

or

```
datatype 'a seq = Seq of unit -> ('a * 'a seq) option;
```

where the empty sequence is encoded by `Seq (fn () => NONE)`.